# Displacing a cosinus curve and keeping zero slope

Tags: calculus, functions

I am doing parametrization and in that regard I need to offset/displace one end of a cosinus curve up along the y-axis.

The function I'm looking at is f(s)=cos(2*pi*s) with s ∈ [0..1] such that it starts and ends in the same point and have zero slope in the endpoints. I want to offset/displace one end of the cosinus with a value p1, therefore I changed the function to f(s)=cos(2*pi*s)+p1*s with s ∈ [0..1], but by adding the term p1*s, the slope at the ends is no longer zero. I've attached two images to show what I mean

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Peter - In that you are new here, perhaps I could mention that helpful answers are usually upvoted. And if you feel that your question has been answered, the answer is accepted. Regards,

Comment: Hi Andrew, I've accepted the answer but I don't have enough reputation to upvote, unfortunately.

Comment: Nice. I'm sure it won't be long till you have plenty of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may for example add a second term $\,\cos(\pi x)$ with an arbitrary coefficient $k$ :
$$f_k(x):=\cos(2\pi\,(1-x))+k\cdot \cos(\pi\,(1-x))$$

For $k=2$ and $k=4$ we get :

[image: k=2]

[image: k=4]

(vertical shifting and scaling should be easy)

A more exotic (but with less 'liberties') solution  is to use $\;\dfrac{\sin(5\pi\,(x-1)/2)}{5\pi\,(x-1)/2)}$ as illustrated :

[image: sin(x)/x]

Hoping this helped,

Comment: Hi Raymond
Thanks a lot for the input. It something similar to the first solution I'm looking for. But I only want to displace the the right endpoint of the curve with the factor k

Comment: @user156046: Well $\,f_k(0)=1-k\,$ and $\,f_k(1)=1+k\,$ so that you need only to shift vertically of $k$ to get a vertical displacement of $2k$. Note that you could too multiply the first $\cos$ function with something like $1-k$ or whatever and that my $1-x$ could be replaced by $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. When k=0 both of the endpoints is at y=1. When k=1 I want the left endpoint (x=0) to be y=1 still, but the right endpoint (x=1) to be y=2.

Comment: @user156046: to be short add $k$ to my expression for $f_k(x)$ and use $p_1=1+2k$ to conclude (or solve if for $k$). Hoping this was clearer,

Comment: Arh great, got it working! Another question though, how can I get the function (both endpoints) to start in $y=0$ instead of $y=1$? Meaning when $k=0$ I want the endpoints to be in $y=0$ but I still want to be able to adjust the right endpoint ($x=1$)

Comment: @PeterHansen: add $k-1$ to my initial $f_k(x)$ so that $\,f_k(0)=1-k+k-1=0\,$ and $\,f_k(1)=1+k+k-1=2k\,$ and you'll have $\,p_1=2k$. For other vertical origins $p_0:=h$ add $k-1+h$ to $f_k(x)$ and use the same method. Fine use,

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I finally got it!